# tf.while_loop only taking into account the last iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop

I am using a tf.while_loop to dynamically concatenate tensors.

**The code**

```
embeds_raw = tf.constant(np.array([
    [1, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [3, 3],
    [3, 3]
], dtype='float32'))
embeds = tf.Variable(initial_value=embeds_raw)
container_variable = tf.zeros([512], dtype=tf.int32, name='container_variable')
sen_len = tf.placeholder('int32', shape=[None], name='sen_len')
# max_l = tf.reduce_max(sen_len)
current_size = tf.shape(sen_len)[0]
padded_sen_len = tf.pad(sen_len, [[0, 512 - current_size]], 'CONSTANT')
added_container_variable = tf.add(container_variable, padded_sen_len)
u1 = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=512, clear_after_read=False)
u1 = u1.split(embeds, added_container_variable)
res = tf.split(embeds, added_container_variable)

i = tf.constant(0, shape=(), dtype='int32', name='i')
x = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0, shape=[2, 2], dtype=tf.float32), dtype=tf.float32)

def condition(_i, _x):
    return tf.less(_i, current_size)

def body(_i, _x):
    return _i + 1, tf.concat([x, u1.read(_i)], axis=0)

idx, x = tf.while_loop(
    condition,
    body,
    [i, x],
    shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None, 2])],
)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sents = sess.run(x, feed_dict={sen_len: [2, 1, 3]})
    print(sents)
    print(len(res))
```

What happens is that it is concatenating at each iteration but dropping the modifications. In other words, the new iteration does not use the previous result.

Here is the output I am getting:

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.]]
```

Whereas my desired output is:

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.]
 [ 3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because this line:

```
return _i + 1, tf.concat([x, u1.read(_i)], axis=0)
```

you should change it to:

```
return _i + 1, tf.concat([_x, u1.read(_i)], axis=0)
```